# Time are being displayed wrong even formatted

Tags: c#, asp.net, time

I'm trying to format a time. I want to show in HH:mm format. I'm passing a Dictionary to my view which contains a list of DateTime objects. It has this format:

```
var mapMovies = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();
```

Pretty simple. Doing this in my view:

```
foreach(var time in movie.Value)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => time.ToString("{0:HH:mm}"))
}
```

When reaches this point I got well known `"Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."` exception. Removing the ToString("{0:HH:mm}") it displays incorrectly in the format {0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}
For me it's a strange thing format the time again because in my model I already do that:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
public DateTime SessionTime { get; set; }
```

If I have defined the way that I want to show in Model, why this is happening?

Comment: remove the brackets.

Comment: How about `time.ToString("HH:mm")`? The modifier `{0}` used if you're using `String.Format`.

Comment: @Gusman Very same error

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Very same error

Comment: Use  {0:t} format

Answer (score 0):

Adopted solution was to format time in controller

```
mapMovies[s.Movie.MovieName].Add(s.SessionTime.ToString("HH:mm"));
```